# Node JS Puppeteer headful Browser doesnt launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium, headless

I'm playing around with puppeteer to learn a bit about automation in the browser. I wanted to open the chromium browser visable so not in headless. I set the launch option to `false`, but it's still not opening Chromium.

I tried to use no sandbox args, i did even deflag the `--disable-extensions` in the args, but nothing helped..

There are no errors in the terminal, it just doesn't launch.

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require ("puppeteer");

async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://google.de");

  await browser.close();
};
```

Any idea why chromium is not opening? Also there are no logs about errors...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problem

You are not calling the function, you are just defining it via `async () => { ... }`. This is why you are not getting any errors, as the function is not executed. In addition, as the other answer already said, you are missing an `await`.

#### Solution

Your code should look like this:

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage(); // missing await
  await page.goto("https://google.de");

  await browser.close();
})(); // Here, we actually call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

newPage() returns a promise so you should await it

```
const puppeteer = require ("puppeteer");

async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://google.de");

await browser.close();
};
```